# Cannot add project to source control

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I've created a new  project in the Solution Explorer then removed it without checking in the solution, then I decided I need the project after all so I created a new one with the same name. No plus sign appeared next to the files this time and now every time I add a new project in the solution, there is no plus sign next to the project and its files and it's not checked in along with existing modified files. New files on existing projects work fine though.

I got the latest version on another pc but creating a new project there would still not give it a plus sign and check it in.

How can I de-confuse the team server?

I've tried getting a specific version and overwriting all files locally in the solution and then recreated the project but nothing changed. Then I deleted the workspace mapping and remapped it but still didn't work.

I'm using visual studio team system 2008 and Team Foundation Server 2008. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually edited the .sln file with Visual Studio closed. Seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Are the project files still in the pending changes window?

I've had cases like this where just removing the new file from the project didn't remove it from the pending changes list. So, if they are undo the "add" for these files and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

This may looks obvius, but if you right click any file in the solution, there's option wich says GO ONLINE?